# Copy/paste an existing (Word *.doc) 'pretty looking' bibliography into LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, symbols, copy-paste

How can I add the list of references into LaTeX? I have a formatted references list in Word and would like to use it in LaTeX. I do not need the connections/the reference in the text itself (cite).
Upcoming problems are:

- signs
- List item

Cheers!!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, but... This question is bordering off-topic for this site. copy paste is a function of whatever editor you are using (you don't say). Having got the text from Word you'd need to mark it up in LaTeX, presumably as some kind of list environment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'signs' and 'list item'? Are those separate problems? If you want a really quick and dirty method, you could save the list of references as an image (e.g. print the page(s) to pdf or whatever) and then just include the image with `\includegraphics...`. However, this would look awful since it will not match the rest of your document. You could try one of the converters available. However, I don't know how well they would do with a list of references. I suspect not very unless the formatting marks them up *as* references in Word, at least.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the text once, copy and paste as text and fix up by hand in your favorite LaTeX editor. A lot of work...

If you might need the references later, do the same, but create a BIBTeX file for them, use \cite{*} to cite them all. A lot more work now, but reusable later. And the formatting wil probably be much better.

Please take the time to learn how to use LaTeX properly, it will pay off handomely.